# interface return either null or defined using sessionstorage

Tags: javascript, sessionstorage

i am making a login form for them to enter their username and password and it works perfectly as their name are displayed on every page. But the problem is if i attempt to access data that does not exist the sessionStorage interface will return either null or undefined. i want a  name stored in the database example welcome!-if the user did not enter their name or welcome!{userid}-if the user enter their name.

```
<html> 
<head>
<title>Login page</title>
<script>
function init(){
var userid = sessionStorage.getItem("userid");

document.write("Welcome "+userid);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;text-align="center";font-size:20pt;
  color:#00FF00;>
 Simple Login Page
</h1>
<form name="myform">
Username<input type="text" name="userid" id="userid"/>
Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
<input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
 </form>

  <script language="javascript">

 function check(form)
 {

 if(form.userid.value && form.pswrd.value)
 {
  location.reload();
 alert("Welcome to this page")
 var userid = document.getElementById("userid").value;
 sessionStorage.setItem("userid", userid);
  }
 else
  {

 alert("Error Password or Username")
  }
  }
 </script>
 <script><!--//

 init()

  //-->

  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

i want to use if else method but i don't know where to put it. Here is the if else code

```
 var userid = sessionStorage.getItem("userid");

 if (userid != "undefined" || userid != "null") {
  document.getElementById('welcomeMessage').innerHTML = "Hello " + userid + "!";
 } else
 document.getElementById('welcomeMessage').innerHTML = "Hello!";
 }
 }
```

Comment: just write `sessionStorage.userid="welcome!";` before `function init(){...`

Comment: it works but it did not display the username.

Comment: add the condition I had posted in the answer too

Answer (score 0):

```
if(sessionStorage.userid==undefined)
     sessionStorage.userid="welcome!"
```